# Change lower bound in Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I have a large number of decision variables `x[i,j,k,l]`. I am using `gurobi` with python. I want to change the lower bound of some `x` which `i` in list. Due to the number of decision variables, what is the best way?
I want to use for loop as minimal as possible. currently, I use the following lines which take too much time. Can I do this with only on loop, i.e. for `i` in list?

```
for i in list:
   for j in J:
     for k in K:
        for l in L:
             model.getVarByName('x[{},{},{},{}]'.format(i,j,k,l)).LB==0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can set the lower bound of a bunch of variables with one simple statement

```
model.setAttr("LB", x, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you created those variables. If you have them available as a multi-dimensional multidict with these indices you could access them right away without iterating through all dimensions and indices. You should avoid getting variables by name.

```
list = ['a','b','c']
x = model.addVars(list, J, K, L)
[model.setAttr('LB', x['a',j,k,l], 0) for i in I for k in K for l in L]
```

You may also rethink whether 4-dimensional variables are the most efficient way to model your problem.